# How to install JCE in Java 1.7 on Mac OS Mountain Lion?

Tags: java, macos, jce

I downloaded the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) for Java 1.7, but I don't find where my JDK is installed.

In terminal, the command "java -version" works fine.

I installed the Mountain Lion from an update, and before was Java 1.7 and Java 1.6 installed on Lion. After I updated, was necessary install Java again, and I installed just Java SE Development Kit 7u40.

Answer (score 0):

JDKs are usually installed here: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk